# AngularJs accordion not opening with is-open attribute

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, accordion, angular-ngmodel

I encountered a strange problem. I had written my own directive. I am trying to use

> is-open

attribute to specify when accordion group needs to be opened based on model named `$scope.state`. Unfortunately it's property isOpen is always false, even when it is changing to true in `checked()` function.

**Directive.html**

```
<accordion>
    <accordion-group class="my-panel-body" ng-class="{'my-panel-heading-checked':state.isOpen,'my-panel-heading-default':!state.isOpen}" is-open="state.isOpen">
         <!--Accordion header -->
         <accordion-heading id="{{groupId}}" >
             <div ng-click="checked()" >
                <i class="pull-left glyphicon" ng-class="status"></i> {{title}}
             </div>
        </accordion-heading>

        <!--Accordion content -->
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

**Directive.js**

```
angular.module('locale').
    directive('accordionList', function () {
        return{
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                title: '=',
                result: '=',
                groupId: '='
            },
            templateUrl: 'html/accordionList.html',
            controller: function($scope){

            var glyphicon = 'glyphicon glyphicon-';
            var status = glyphicon + 'unchecked';
            $scope.state = {
                isOpen: false
            }
            $scope.status = status;

            $scope.checked =  function(){
                console.log($scope.state.isOpen) //It is always false!
                if ($scope.state.isOpen) {
                    $scope.state.isOpen = false;
                    $scope.status = status;
                }
                else {   //Always entering this part of code!
                    console.log("FLAG");
                    $scope.state.isOpen = true; //True only here when invoked.
                    $scope.status = glyphicon + 'check';
                    console.log($scope.state.isOpen);  

                }
            }          
        }
   };
```

});

I would be grateful for any help. I have no idea what is not working.

Comment: Can you make a plunker or fiddle for it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your provided code, I created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/KfJsSWD6OlhhSX2pa1t7?p=preview) to reproduce your issue and it does show the problem.

The fact is that the `accordion-group` directive will auto bind a `toggleOpen` function to click event (see the [template](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/accordion/accordion-group.html#L3)). In this case, with your own `checked` function your `isOpen` value is changed twice when element get clicked, and thus remains unchanged.

so just eliminate the 'check()' or stop changing `isOpen` value in it.

```
$scope.checked =  function(){

                console.log($scope.state.isOpen) //It is always false!
                if ($scope.state.isOpen) {
                    //$scope.state.isOpen = false;
                    $scope.status = status;
                }
                else {   //Always entering this part of code!
                    console.log("FLAG");
                  //  $scope.state.isOpen = true; //True only here when invoked.
                    $scope.status = glyphicon + 'check';
                    console.log($scope.state.isOpen);  

                }
            }
```

Comment: thank You for quick resposne. I will check tomorrow if it will fix the issue.

Comment: hmm, it helped but now i have no idea how to invoke function for instance when my accordion collapse. When i click on it to close it up, $scope.state.isOpen  is true in checked() function-when it is closing. But i would like to do some stuff when the $scope.state.isOpen is false already.(after collapsing and going through checked func. How i could i achieve that>